# Play audio and video with gnonlin

Tags: python, streaming, gstreamer, multimedia, gnonlin

I've been messing around with Gstreamer and Gnonlin lately, I've been concatenating segments of video files but when I dynamically connect the src pad on the composition, I can choose either the audio or video portion of the files, producing silent playback or videoless audio. How can I attach my composition to an audioconverter and a video sink at the same time. Do I have to make two compositions and add the files to both them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gnonlin compositions work on one media type at a time.  Audio and Video are treated separately.